# C++ XOR encryption truncates file

Tags: c++, file, encryption, file-io, xor

I'm currently trying to implement file encryption via XOR. Simple as it is, though, I struggle with encryption of *multiline* files.
Actually, my first problem was that XOR can produce zero chars, which are interpreted as line-end by `std::string`, thus my solution was:

```
std::string Encryption::encrypt_string(const std::string& text) 
{  //encrypting string

    std::string result = text;  

    int j = 0;  
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)  
    {
        result[i] = 1 + (result[i] ^ code[j]);  
        assert(result[i] != 0);  

        j++;  
        if(j == code.length())  
            j = 0;  
    }
    return result;  
}

std::string Encryption::decrypt_string(const std::string& text)
{ // decrypting string
    std::string result = text;
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
    {
        result[i] = (result[i]  - 1) ^ code[j];
        assert(result[i] != 0);

        j++;
        if(j == code.length())
            j = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Not neat, but fine for the first attempt. But when trying to crypt text files, I understood, that depending on encryption key, my output file gets truncated in random places. My best thought was, that `\n` is handled incorrectly, because strings from keyboard (even with `\n`) don't break the code.

```
bool Encryption::crypt(const std::string& input_filename, const std::string& output_filename, bool encrypt)          
{ //My file function
    std::fstream finput, foutput;
    finput.open(input_filename, std::fstream::in);
    foutput.open(output_filename, std::fstream::out);

    if (finput.is_open() && foutput.is_open())
    {
        std::string str;
        while (!finput.eof())
        {
            std::getline(finput, str);
            if (encrypt)
                str.append("\n");
            std::string encrypted = encrypt ? encrypt_string(str) : decrypt_string(str);  
            foutput.write(encrypted.c_str(), str.length());
        }

        finput.close();
        foutput.close();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

What could be the problem, given that console input is XOR'ed fine?

Comment: `getline()` consumes the `'\n'` (new line) characters. You should read your file using the `std::ifstream::read()` function.

Comment: Having `\0` in a string is fine, you just need to be carefull to not use functions using it as marker for end of string. If you're just working with strings and calling write the way you do in your example (with `.c_str()` or `.data()` and `.length()`), you should be fine.

Comment: πάντα-ῥεῖ is right, if you only have issue with `multiline` files, you should look for your issue in the handling of end of lines !

Comment: When dealing with binary data (instead of character data), you must use byte buffers (arrays of unsigned char) instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

> XOR can produce zero chars, which are interpreted as line-end by `std::string`

`std::string` provides overloads to most functionality which allow you to specify the size of input data. It allows you to also check for the size of the stored data. Therefore, a 0-value `char` inside of `std::string` is perfectly reasonable and acceptable.

Therefore, the problem isn't `std::string` treating nulls as end-of-line but perhaps `std::getline()` which may be doing that.

I see that you're using `std::ostream::write()` so I see you're already familiar with using sizes as parameters. So why not also use `std::istream::read()` instead of `std::getline()`?

Therefore, you can simply read in "chunks" or "blocks" of the file instead of needing to treat line separators as a special case.